# Local File Download(LFD) vulnerability exploit

Tags: web-application, exploit, databases, asp.net

I have found a arbitrary file download vulnerability in an asp.net application.
I've downloaded the web.config and some other files. So what can i do with that "web.config" information ?(for example: connecting to database)

This is an piece of web.config fiele:

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="project" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.20.8;Database=newdatabase;User ID=sa;Password=123456Aa" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:
Check the server if SQL access from hosts other than `localhost` is possible.

1. Log in to the SQL Server and see if you have access to any other databases or tables that could be interesting. (User accounts,...)
2. Authenticated SQL Exploits now become a possibility.
3. Try this password on other known users as they might've been reused.